# Convert Nullable<Boolean> to Generic type

Tags: c#, generics, exception, c#-4.0, nullable

Assume this method:

```
public T GetParameterValue<T>(string ParamName) {

if(typeof(T) == typeof(Boolean?) && Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains(ParamName)) {

                Boolean? istrue = null;

                if(Request.QueryString.GetValues(ParamName).FirstOrDefault() == "1")
                    istrue = true;
                else if(Request.QueryString.GetValues(ParamName).FirstOrDefault() == "0")
                    istrue = false;

                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(istrue, typeof(T));
            }

//Other types implementation

}
```

So this method always rise an exception in return line:

```
Invalid cast from 'System.Boolean' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean, 
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
```

I don't understand where is the problem I don't use `Boolean` I use `Boolean?`

this is my call line:

```
Product.IsAllow= GetParameterValue<Boolean?>("IsAllow");
```

So what is your idea about it?

Comment: Not an answer, but why the conditional. Just do `isTrue=Request.QueryString.GetValues(ParamName).FirstOrDefault() == "1"`

Comment: @JohnFx: there's a third state, where the return value might be null.  `!= "1"` doesn't necessarily mean `== "0"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
return (T)(object)istrue;
```

I would not use this kind of code at all though. Simply create a method that specifically parses each data type (e.g. `bool? GetBooleanParameter(string name)`). You're not gaining anything with the generics here and only making the code more cumbersome.

Comment: Would this be applicable/work the same, if T is passed as bool, and not Boolean?

Comment: I am testing it out, and it produces the same result.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand where is the problem I don't use `Boolean` I use `Boolean?`

Yes, but you're unknowingly converting it to `Boolean` before `ChangeType` sees it.

The first parameter has type `Object`. When a nullable value type, in this case `bool?`, is converted to `object`, you either get `null`, or an instance of the non-nullable type. So by the time `ChangeType` sees it, it's no longer a nullable boolean.

The real problem is that `Converter` just doesn't support nullable types. At best, you could special case, if the type is `T?`, check if the parameter is null or an empty string, if so, return null, otherwise, convert to `T`. Or not use `Converter` where it's not the best way to go.